# Where's the reference node in a VS 2017 ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I just created a new web app project in VS 2017.  I went to add a reference to active directory (system.directoryServices) and noticed that the reference node is missing.  I don't see any way to add system references in the web app?  There's a "Dependencies" node but that appears to be only for custom projects.  Anyone know where this was moved to?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your UI? (Especially the Solution Explorer)

Comment: What type of project is it? .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET Standard? Does it multi-target multiple platforms?

Comment: Sure, I just added the picture above.  

It's .net Core 2.0

Comment: You don't add framework references in .NET Core. You use NuGet packages for absolutely everything

Comment: I was wondering about that... But I don't see an active directory NuGet Package...

Comment: Look for `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` **check preview packages**

Comment: THANK YOU!  I didn't realize it was a prerelease.

Comment: It is part of the Windows Compatability Pack for .NET Core. Will run only on Windows.